# Não consigo desabilitar um checkbox com enable = false

Tags: javascript

Preciso, em determinadas situações, habilitar ou não um checkbox. Fiz uma função em JavaScript e não consigo habilitar/desabilitar. Eis abaixo a função:

```
function ValidaCampoInserirAutorizacao(){
        var vTussMed  = document.getElementById('ind_tipo_mat_med_hid').value;
        var vSituacao = document.getElementById('ind_situacao_hid').value;
        var vClassif  = document.getElementById('cod_grupo_mat_med_hid').value;
        var vGrupEst  = document.getElementById('cod_grupo_estatistico_hid').value;

        if(vTussMed == '5' && vClassif == '998' && vGrupEst == 'MED' && vSituacao == 'A'){
            document.getElementById('ind_permite_inc_autori_chkb').enable = true;
        }else{
            document.getElementById('ind_permite_inc_autori_chkb').enable = false;
        }       
    }
```

Essa função é chamada nos eventos `onchange` dos `radiobutton`s e de dois `select`'s.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Para **desativar** (deixar ele cinza e inutilizável) um checkbox a propriedade correta é `disabled` e não `enable`

Mude:

```
document.getElementById('ind_permite_inc_autori_chkb').enable = true;

document.getElementById('ind_permite_inc_autori_chkb').enable = false;
```

Para:

```
document.getElementById('ind_permite_inc_autori_chkb').disabled = true;

document.getElementById('ind_permite_inc_autori_chkb').disabled = false;
```

Comment: Eis que temos a resposta! Como recomendado pelo site da W3: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_checkbox_disabled2

Answer (score 7):

O nome correto da propriedade é `checked` para marcado/desmarcado e `disabled` para desabilitado/habilitado. Veja e teste no exemplo abaixo:

```js
function teste1() {
    document.getElementById('teste').checked = true;
}

function teste2() {
    document.getElementById('teste').checked = false;
}

function teste3() {
    document.getElementById('teste').disabled = true;
}

function teste4() {
    document.getElementById('teste').disabled = false;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="teste" />
<input type="button" value="marcar" onclick="teste1()" />
<input type="button" value="desmarcar" onclick="teste2()" />
<input type="button" value="desabilitar" onclick="teste3()" />
<input type="button" value="habilitar" onclick="teste4()" />
```

Answer (score 4):

Tu pode usar a propriedade `disabled` ao invés de `enable`, segue um exemplo:

```js
document.getElementById('click').addEventListener('click', function() {
  document.getElementById('check').disabled = !document.getElementById('check').disabled;  
});
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="check" disabled="">
<br>
<button id="click">Habilitar/Desabilitar</button>
```

Answer (score 4):

Tente assim, usando o mesmo botão para habilitar e desabilitar:

```js
function habilita() {

  var check = document.getElementById("ind_permite_inc_autori_chkb");
  var botao = document.getElementById("habilitar");
  if (check.disabled) {
    check.removeAttribute("disabled");
    botao.value = "Desabilitar";
  } else {
    check.disabled = "true";
    botao.value = "Habilitar";
  }

}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="ind_permite_inc_autori_chkb" value="habilitado">
<input type="button" id="habilitar" value="Habilitar" onClick="habilita()">
```